# Unable to start Apache Tomcat 8 and asks to edit and save tomcat-users.xml

Tags: java, tomcat8

Unable to start Tomcat8 server after successful installation on Ubuntu 15.04.

Shows message on browser "It works!" on accessing `localhost:8080`

It asks to edit and save "/etc/tomcat8/tomcat-users.xml" file but not allowing to edit and save with root user due to access right issue.

Not even able to "edit and save" with

> role rolename="manager"/>

> role rolename="admin"/>

> user name="admin" password="secret" roles="manager,admin"/> "

using vi editor with sudo `sudo vi /etc/tomcat8/tomcat-users.xml`.

No access on link: http://localhost:8080/manager/html.Log

Comment: Hi @Nizami Firdaous If you are running in linux, you should take read/write permission access from root user. I guess according your words, you are facing permission issue.

Comment: @Nizami do you have root access of your server?? Why do you want to edit `tomcat-users.xml` file??

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking interest on above query... Actually, It's access permission issue and I was not getting option to modify it. Hence I installed Windows now and it's running properly.

Comment: @Jar Yit, yes edit permission was missing, worked on applying.